# Embedded python fails to compile on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, c, linux, gcc

I installed python 3.9.1 on my Raspberry Pi following the instructions here https://www.ramoonus.nl/2020/10/06/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-raspberry-pi/ and set it as the default python interpreter. I got my compiling and linking parameters for embedded Python following the instructions here https://docs.python.org/3.9/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems

I tried a simple test with the following code (test.c) :

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

and then

`gcc -I/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/include/python3.9 -I/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/include/python3.9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -c test.c -o test.o`

and

`gcc -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -o test.o`

and got

`/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function '_start': /build/glibc-P1SmLh/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119: undefined reference to 'main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Trying to compile the example at https://docs.python.org/3.9/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding throws the same error. What could the problem be?

Edit:
After Expolarity's comment I changed the linker command to:

`gcc test.o -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -o test`

which seems to have worked but threw me a bunch of other errors:

test.o: In function `main': /home/pi/Downloads/test.c:6: undefined reference to` Py_DecodeLocale'
/home/pi/Downloads/test.c:11: undefined reference to `Py_SetProgramName' /home/pi/Downloads/test.c:12: undefined reference to` Py_Initialize'
/home/pi/Downloads/test.c:13: undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags' /home/pi/Downloads/test.c:15: undefined reference to` Py_Finalize'
/home/pi/Downloads/test.c:16: undefined reference to `PyMem_RawFree'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This seems more serious. Any ideas?

Comment: The line `gcc /usr/bin/g++ -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/...` doesn't contain the object file `test.o` (which contains your `main` function) and would try to compile or link `/usr/bin/g++` instead. Don't you get an error message about `/usr/bin/g++`?

Comment: I believe typing just test as I have done instead of test.o is the same. I tried test.o and still throws the same error.

Comment: If you tried other commands, please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact command and the output instead of vaguely describing what you did. To be more clear about my previous comment: In the linker command, remove `/usr/bin/g++` and add `test.o` instead.

Comment: you're attempting to run an unlinked ELF object file, you need to link it in order for it to be an ELF executable. to be exact, this command should work: `gcc test.o -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -o test`

Comment: Alright, that's progress! It seems you forgot to link towards the python library, try `gcc test.o -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib -lpython3.9 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -o test`, the uppercase `-L` option specifies directories to look for libraries (which are then specified using the lowercase `-l`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tttapa's answer over [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119453/embedded-python-fails-to-compile) it finally worked by adjusting the linker command as so:

`gcc test.o -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.1/lib -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython3.9 -o test`

Edit: Expolarity also answered correctly just after tttapa. Thanks a lot everyone!